# Will a 3ds be fine if a cartridge is removed while it is running?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

My little sister took my game out of my 3ds while it was on and the game was still on, and I am worried. Are there any glitches that might occur after this incident?

After I realized she did this I switched my 3DS off and I didn't put it on charge.

Is there anything going to happen? I am worried I just want to be ready for any lags or glitches that might happen but I didn't save in the Poké Center I never do (Pokémon Sun was in there and I saved before I got earthquake and teached miltank earthquake so not much was lost)

But will my game and 3DS be fine after this incident?

Comment: Probably just lost some progress.

Comment: For future reference: If your game was still in progress, Yes, you will lose some progress/data. If you were on the home menu, No, you will be absolutely fine, don't worry. In the future: Make sure you save after _every_ major in-game accomplishment (trial, key item, league battle etc.), so that nothing big will be left unsaved.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you weren't in the middle of saving when the incident occurred, you'll be fine. The only problem with removing the cartridge while the system/game is on is the game will no longer play(until you put the cart back in and restart the system), and any unsaved progress will likely be lost.

If you remove the cartridge/power off the system while it is saving, there is a chance your save data could get corrupted and you would be forced to start over (varies from game to game)

Answer (score 3):

Your 3DS will be fine. I've taken my game out of my cartridge many times while it was running and I've had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Over the past few years, I'v had multiple 3d's due to dropping and breaking. Over those years I popped cartridges out while the system was still running. Apart from slowing down a bit for a few seconds while it stops the game, your 3ds should be fine. Iv had the 3ds, 3ds XL and the NEW 3ds XL and all still work fine afterward